# Picking random elements as well as elements from 20th/40th row away in R?

Tags: r, csv

Apologies if this is a bit of a stupid question, I'm very new to R.

I have a data set of around 3000 in a column in a csv file. I've imported the data in and now what I want to do is create a sample of 200 vectors that have 3 values, the value in a randomly selected row, the value in the row 20 rows down from that row, and the value in the row 40 rows down.

For example, if the value selected is in the 1st row, I want to vector to look like,

v = (value in first row, value in 21st row, value in 41st row).

I've used `sample("dataset", 200)` which gives me 200 random values like I want, but I want each value to have two corresponding values from the rows that are 20 and 40 below.

Any tips on what I could do?

Comment: If the value selected is in the 2990th row, what is the expected vector?

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I want the randomly selected values to come from the first 2960 rows so that I have the 2 corresponding values.

Comment: Do you accept duplicates?

Comment: No duplicates for the selected number (first entry in the vector), but it would be fine if say the 20th row after one selected number, became the first entry for another vector. That does sound confusing I know, sorry. Say something like, v1=(11th entry,31st entry, 41st entry), v2 = (31st entry, 51st entry, 71st entry) would be fine as 2 separate vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind duplicates, then the following should work:

```
x <- 1:3000 # Your data
set.seed(123) # Only for reproducibility purposes

s <- sort(sample(2960, size=200))  # Sample indicies (sorting is optional)
i <- c(s, s+20, s+40)  # Add the 20th and 40th values further down
sam <- x[i]  # Select the values using the indicies

head(sort(sam))
[1] 13 33 41 53 61 81
```

This may result in duplicates.

```
length(unique(sam))
# 562
```

---

If you want the order as described, then this should work:

```
set.seed(123)
s <- sort(sample(2960, size=200))
sam1 <- x[s]
sam20 <- x[s+20]
sam40 <- x[s+40]
sam <- as.vector(rbind(sam1, sam20, sam40))
head(sam)
# [1] 13 33 53 41 61 81
```

Comment: I was just about to ask how I might do that, I get the values that I want with your code, thank you very much btw. Ordering like that would greatly help me construct the vectors

Comment: That gives me exactly what I'm looking for, thanks so much.